# Grails -- Update a domain object with a null Date

Tags: grails

In a domain object, here's the relevant snippet of my data structure and constraints block

```
Date printed

static constraints =
{
    printed (Display:false, nullable:true)      
}
```

and then I wrote this method

```
def resetPrinted()
{
    printed = null
    save()
}
```

When I execute that method, `printed` gets set to the current date, not null.

I have found a fair number of people complaining about this issue, but I have yet to find an actual solution.  Here's what I've found so far:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-6943

http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Grails-1-3-4-won-t-accept-null-dates-td2322178.html

http://java.dzone.com/tips/null-value-save-issue-grails

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7189

I'm using Grails 2.2.4.  If this has been somehow fixed in 2.3.0, I'll upgrade, but otherwise I'd rather not.

Comment: It works as expected when tested through console in 2.2.4. How does your implementation look like?

Comment: dmahapatro, you're correct, this wasn't really the problem.  I hadn't noticed a `beforeUpdate()` method which was also altering `printed`.  Should I delete this question, since it turned out to be useless, and will only be distracting to future readers?

Comment: I suggest you add an answer with whatever you faced and found out (how and why `beforeUpdate()`) was blocking you, and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I hadn't noticed the presence of a `beforeUpdate()` method, which was calling `setStatusDate()`.  These are the relevant sections of that method:

```
def setStatusDate()
{
    def now = new Date()
    ...
    else if(status == Status.PRINTED)
        printed = now
    ...
}
```

So `resetPrinted()` was setting it to null, but right before the update happened, `beforeUpdate()` was triggering, which called `setStatusDate()`, and set it back to `now`.

**CONCLUSION**: if data is going awry, check for the presence of these methods: `beforeInsert, beforeUpdate, beforeDelete, beforeValidate, afterInsert, afterUpdate, afterDelete,` and `onLoad`